# Why did civicrm_status_pref table not get created during upgrade

Tags: upgrade

we had an upgrade (4.4 > 4.7) that resulted in drupal log errors telling us DB Error: no such table ... civicrm_status_pref though there had been no warnings during upgrade itself

Answer (score 1):

We turned logging off and back on, and table was created and several other problems were fixed (eg cron warnings in system status.

Reminder, to self and others, that for upgrading old systems in particular, turning logging off/on can be a help